# Artificial Neural Network Toplogy

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence

I am currently trying to revise for my final year exams and came across this question, I have looked everywhere in my lecture slides for any sort of help and cannot find any. Any help in providing insight in to how to solve this question would be appreciated (I am not just asking for the answer, I need to comprehend the topic). Furthermore, do I assume that all inputs are equal to 1? Do i include 7 inputs in the input layer? Im at a loss as to how to answer.

The question is as follows:

b)   Determine, with justification, the simplest type and topology (i.e. number of neurons & layers) of artificial neural network that could learn the data set below.

[Click here for picture of the dataset.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aVjPJ.png)

Comment: Please put the problem description into the question. If it absolutely cannot be described in text, use an image. Please don't make us go to yet another site to see the problem.

Comment: @lit my profile restricts me from including embedded images, the link is simply providing the image.

Comment: That is a simple data set; include it as text.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not mistaken, you have two inputs X1, X2, and one target output. For each input consisting, of two numbers X1, X2, the appropriate output ("target") is given.

As a first step, you could sketch the seven data points - just draw the 3 ones and 4 zeroes at the right places on on the square (X1, X2) ∈ [0, 1.05] × [0, 1]. Maybe you remember something similar from the lecture, possibly near a mention of "XOR".

Answer (score 0):

The edit queue is full, so adding data from the linked image here

```
Pattern X1  X2  Target  
1   0.01    -0.1    1   
2   0.90    0.09    0   
3   0.89    -0.05   0   
4   1.05    0.95    1   
5   -0.01   0.12    0   
6   1.05    0.97    1   
7   0.98    0.10    0
```

It looks like 1 possible solution is X1 >= 1.0 OR X2 <= -0.1

Alternatively, if you round each of X1 and X2, it becomes

```
Pattern X1  X2  Target  
1   0   0   1
2   1   0   0
3   1   0   0
4   1   1   1
5   0   0   0
6   1   1   1
7   1   0   0
```

Then it *IS* XOR, and the solution is round(X1) XOR round(X2).  In that case you can use 1 activation layer (like round, RELU, sigmoid, linear), 1 hidden layer of 2 neurons and 1 output layer of 1 neuron.

[See this stackoverflow post for a detail of how to solve XOR with a neural net.](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/11589/creating-neural-net-for-xor-function)